# Update (or set before redirect) back button url in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Scenario:

User is on site http://www.someWhere.com/here?query1=abc

User clicks on a link to go http://www.someWhere.com/there

If the user clicks on the back button, they would go back to http://www.someWhere.com/here?query1=abc

Is there a way to update the "back button" url to be http://www.someWhere.com/here?query2=xyz instead?

In order of preference I would prefer a solution in AngularJS, JQuery, or JavaScript.